# Get the index of element in difference array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've two arrays

```
var valid = ["a", "b"];
var different = ["a", "c", "b"];
```

What is the best way to find out the position of element different? Only one element can be different.

In this case the different array change only by one element and I want the index (**1**) of different array.

Comment: Loop and index of? Or loop and compare? Multiple ways of doing it.

Comment: I need index of element different in second array (in this case named different)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this. For instance, you could iterate over the `valid` array and when the values don't match up, then you know the `index` of the different value. In this case, it is `1`.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ssk5gnya/)

```
var valid = ["a", "b"];
var different = ["a", "c", "b"];

valid.forEach(function (value, i) {
  if (value !== different[i]) {
    console.log(i); // 1
  }
});
```

Comment: I need it without forEach because is async and I cannot exit from the loop

Answer (score 0):

Returns the index of the differing value:

```js
var valid = ['a', 'b'];
var different = ['a', 'c', 'b'];

var diffIndex = valid.findIndex(function (value, index) {
  return value !== different[index];
});

alert('Array differs at index: ' + diffIndex);
```

Note that `findIndex` is part of the ES2015 standard.